# EAS build react navite app .env variables

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables, eas

When I try to run my project with expo it uses .env.development.local.

But when I try to build my project with EAS, it does not use .env.development.local or .env.production.local. What are the right names I need? I know that I can use env variables inside *eas.json*. But I think its bad practice, because I don't want to store env data in my GIT.

My eas.json:

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  }
}
```